# Magento 2: Is it possible to add a comment in a field?

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I have a custom attribute in the account information of user (backend).

Now I need to add a comment on the bottom of the field.

[image]

**Code of the attribute:**

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'mod_freetext',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => __('Free Text'),
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'required' => 0,
            'visible' => 1,
            'user_defined' => 0,
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 620
        ]
);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a key `note` in your array as follow :

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
    'mod_freetext',
    [
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => __('Free Text'),
        'input' => 'textarea',
        'required' => 0,
        'visible' => 1,
        'user_defined' => 0,
        'system' => 0,
        'position' => 620,

        /** Add a note */
        'note' => 'Here is a note'
    ]
);
```